# Generating a new, more dense grids using existing and scale

Tags: python, numpy, grid

I use Python for fitting various experimental data.

The data I have is stored in NumPy arrays, e.g.

```
x = np.array([53.821593,  53.85265044, 53.88373501, 53.91484627, 53.94598466, 53.97714997, 54.00834218, 54.03956172, 54.07080797, 54.10208155, 54.13338225, 54.16471028,
 54.19606522, 54.2274477])
```

where x stands for some coordinate of experimental data.

the distance between elements of an x array varies (the grid is nonuniform and some regions along the axis have ).

I need a package or a function to create a new grid based on the initial grid but more dense and will include the coordinates of the initial grid.

```
def resample_grid(initial_grid: np.array, scale: float) -> np.array:
```

Something that will add additional points between the given points using some provided parameter, e.g. scale so the new grid will have (x.size * scale) points (approx.), while the left and right borders of the new grid must be the same as in the initial.

It's preferable that this function/tool will not give random values, so the result of applying it to the initial array will have a steady result.

Is there any package or solution?

Edited:
To be more specific - it's required to obtain a new grid with the known number of points in the resulting array that includes old coordinates and adds new ones to obtain a "more uniform" grid, e.g. by adding points in regions where the grid is too coarse and do not touch regions where we have maximum density values. So the resulting grid will have a "more uniform" grid - to minimize the mean length of intervals in the new grid (and the variance of lengths) for resulting array in comparison with the initial grid.

```
def resample_grid(initial_grid: np.array, num_out_points: int) -> np.array:
```

Comment: Did you search for this?  `scipy.signal.resample` and `scipy.signal.resample_poly` can interpolate signals like this.

Comment: You need to be specific. That is, you should define the exact model of your desired grid. For example, simply taking evenly spaced points for each inverval can be done by ```np.append(np.hstack(np.linspace(x[:-1], x[1:], 10, endpoint=False, axis=1)), x[-1])```.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, it's cool. 1) I have edited the question to be more specific. 2) is there a way to use similar approach to that one you provided but with varying  number of subintervals for each pair of points in initial grid? E.g. if I have a list with numbers intervals_num[1,3,4...] that carries the number of points for each interval - so we will not divide zero interval (between points 0 and 1), first interval (between points 1 and 2) on 3 subintervals, second (between 2 and 3) on 4 subintervals and so on. The number of steps for each interval is stored in a separate list.

Comment: Use a for loop or list comprehension, like ```np.hstack([np.linspace(x[i], x[i+1], intervals_num[i], endpoint=(i==len(x)-2)) for i in range(len(x)-1)])```. And FYI, to notify a commenter like me, you need to write like ```@relent95```.